# How open a stack of .tif images with python

Tags: python, numpy, stack, python-imaging-library, opencv

i have a file with 300 .tif images, i want to open it with python and save them into an array, list or any similar structure. I´ve tried the code below but only appears 3 images. ¿Any solution?. Thanks.

```
raw = cv2.imread('sen_15Hz_500Hz_6_6A.tif')
print(np.shape(raw))
```

[image]

I´ve tried with PIL and cv2 too.

Comment: what do you mean with "only appears 3 images"? Your code load one image and print the shape.

Comment: Use cv2.imreadmulti()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really have one single TIFF file with 300 images in it, the simplest is to open it with [tifffile](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/).

```
with TiffFile('temp.tif') as tif:
   for page in tif.pages:
      image = page.asarray()
```

---

If you want to use **PIL** look at the section *"Image Sequences"* [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/tutorial.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there a way to count the pages of the tiff file using tifffile module?