# Remove corrupt exif warnings with tiff images

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to fix the corrupt exif warnings from tiff images and here's a code I am using

```
from PIL import Image

def remove_exif(image_name):
    image = Image.open(image_name)
    if not image.getexif():
        return
    print('removing EXIF from', image_name, '...')
    data = list(image.getdata())
    image_without_exif = Image.new(image.mode, image.size)
    image_without_exif.putdata(data)

    image_without_exif.save(image_name)


remove_exif('ggg.tiff')
print('Done')
```

The code is working and removed the exif but I got one page only while the tiff before the exif remove was of two pages.
Is it possible to keep all the pages of the tiff image?

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75219693/2836621